# How to print "\n" character using bash?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I have a .csv file where some strings have some special characters like "\n" (new line).

I'm using this script to extract the data from column 1 and 3:

```
while IFS=";" read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
        echo "\"$f1\" = \"$f3\";"
done < file.csv >file.txt
```

The main problem is that in some ***$f3*** I have the ***\n*** special character and I need to print it.

At the moment, this script is omitting this character.

e.g. If I have

> \nXPTO

it will print

> XPTO

and I would expect that would print

> \nXPTO

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "a;b;\nXPTO;d" | awk -F';' '{print $1 "=" $3}'

a=\nXPTO
```

or with file in/out

```
$ awk ... input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `read -r` to prevent `read` from interpreting escape sequences:

```
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 f4
do
    echo "\"$f1\" = \"$f3\";"
done < file.csv >file.txt
```

Side Note: While it can be done with `bash` as I showed above, I agree with [Karafka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39757759/171318) that `awk` is ideal for that kind of problems and performs very well. Better than bash itself, having that the input file has a significant size.